# How can i customize the comment list

Tags: theme-development, customization, comment-form

I am using **wp_list_comments()** function  to draw the comment list.But,I want change many things in the form like class,styles, reply link and etc...

so please help me, How can i customize the comment listing function

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean form (used to submit new comment) or listing of existing comments?

Comment: @Rarst:listing of existing comments !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wp_list_comments()` call accepts a *callback* argument, in which you can define the *specifc* comment-list markup that you want. I would suggest taking a look at how TwentyTen handles the `wp_list_comments()` callback.

Answer (score 5):

You could just take a look at the [Codex Page for wp_list_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) which has some example code for customising comment listings.

You will see from that page that you can add a callback function to `wp_list_comments` which is normally used to customise how comments are listed

Comment: +1 I kinda forgot that it takes callback as well. That might be easier than custom Walker.

Comment: Twenty Ten uses a comment callback function which might be a good example to start with.

Comment: Updated answer to specifically mention the callback, which was my main reason for suggesting the Codex page.

Comment: Up-voted since you edited to mention the callback explicitly (thus making my answer redundant, and yours more thorough). :)

Answer (score 3):

[`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) uses `Walker_Comment` class (that extends generic [`Walker`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class)) to generate output.

If you need extensive customization you should extend `Walker_Comment` with your own class and pass instance of it as `walker` argument to the function.

Comment: can you give me simple example.

Comment: @gowri unfortunately nothing about walkers is simple. You need to understand first both mechanics of Walker class in WP (see linked Codex article) and concepts of [PHP object inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Answer (score 2):

Comment is Easily Customaziable.
for example: code for cancel the reply link

```
<?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?>
```

---

if you want custom the Text like Reply means Replace Text...

```
<?php cancel_comment_reply_link(text); ?>
```

Text to display as a link. If empty, it will return the default: 'Click here to cancel reply.'it should be work.

Comment: Do you think,this can solve my whole problem. because I want change many thinks in comment listing. so any other idea

Comment: i gave the solution to change your reply link only.not to all.if you want to customize class means you will need to do some more things....

Comment: you may go for that [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Theme_Forms)

Comment: even I am not talking about canceling the reply. I just want to replace reply by some images.Anyway thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using [comment_form();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form). It will give you a default layout of a comment form but you can pass `$args` to it to modify each section.

Comment: I am taking about comment listing

Comment: @gowri but your question says you want to change the form...